# UFT 11.51 - "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Tags: save, qtp, hp-uft

I get this when I try to save my test either from QC (ALM connection) or locally.

"Sequence Contains more than one matching element"

I cannot Save As neither.

I use UFT 11.51 on XP.

Question is if anybody else had had this. And if there is any solution or workaround to it.

Thanks in advance,
Mateo

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question is if anybody else had had this. And if there is any solution or workaround to it. Thanks.

Comment: any ideas??? it is happening again...

Comment: Try to reproduce, I mean: in a controlled manner. Then folks can help. For now, try closing and re-opening UFT. Will 90% "help". If is does not, reboot. QTP/UFT generally is not the stablest piece of software on earth, I am experiencing a couple of freezes per day...in QTP 11 the safest way to get QTP freezing is using the spy. The more it hightlights, the sooner you´ll die.

Comment: And yes this totally sucks.

Comment: i have tried what you said and more! i think i will have to install it one another machine or something. ALL OF A SUDDEN BOOM! I have install 11.52 and still S$%$T...

Comment: Deinstall, reboot, delete registry keys and file system directories that are leftover, and re-install. And contacting tech support ;-(

Comment: Installed UFT 12. It seems a biiiiiiiiiiiiit more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Latest 12.02 version of UFT, I faced the same issue, one possible reason for this issue is the Action Name.

In my case I had used an action name as "ArticlePullQuote", called it from another action within the same test and try to save it, QTP throws error "Sequence Contains more than one matching element".

I changed the action name to "ArtPullQuote", and tried to save, it worked fine.

This might not be the solution for all, but give a try.